# Следует ли создавать отдельную таблицу в БД для вспомогательного класса UserAddress Java, Hibernate, Postgres?

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, hibernate, шаблоны-проектирования

Я делаю небольшой рестфул сервис для управления пользователями. По заданию Пользователь определяется следующими значениями:

```
◦ Имя
◦ Фамилия
◦ Дата рождения
◦ Логин 
◦ Пароль 
◦ Поле ввода “О себе” 
◦ Адрес проживания (страна, город, улица, дом, квартира)
```

При проектировании я обратил внимание на адрес и подумал, что неправильно записывать все вместе в одно поле address и делать аналогичный атрибут в таблице базы данных, ведь тогда очень неудобной станет разная фильтрация по адресам. После чего я разграничил поле адрес на 5 полей(те что указаны в скобках). Впрочем, сделав так, я осознал, что мой класс с учетом поля id имеет 12 полей, что в моем понимании, делает класс слишком нагруженным и "неправильным". Тогда я решил сделать отдельный класс для адреса и использовать его в качестве поля у пользователя, а именно:

```
@Entity
public class UserAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private int house;
    private int flat;

}
```

И сделав так, я не совсем уверен как мне быть дальше, в следствии чего у меня возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Стоит ли выносить 5 полей для адреса в отдельный класс в UserAddres?
2. Если да, то стоит ли делать этот класс Entity и создавать под него таблицы в БД?
3. Нужно ли относится к нему, как к полноценному классу (создавать геттеры/сеттеры, equals and hashcode, сервисный уровень)?
4. Не станет ли фильтрация пользователей по адресу еще более сложной, чем при изначальном варианте?
5. Как вообще лучше поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: 1. зависит от тех.залдания (скорее всего да) 2.да, если п.1 да. 3.да, если п.1 да. 4.нет. 5.все уже описано за исключением связи между классами: один к одному

Comment: По поводу 5 пункта, такую связь следует обозначить в каждом классе?

Comment: да, фактически теперь каждый класс будет содержать переменную типа другого класса

Comment: [How are Value Objects stored in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/679005/312041)

Comment: Это называется приведение к нормальным формам при проектировании бд

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, но не все 5.
2. Нет.
3. Да, нужно.
4. Наоборот, упроститься
5. См. пример ниже:

Я предлагаю тебе сделать класс `Address` отдельным классом, но при этом пометить его как `@Embeddable`.

В твоем случае:

```java
@Embeddable
public class UserAddress {

    private String country;

    private String city;

    private String street;

    private int house;

    private int flat;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private UserAddress userAddress;
}
```

Затем в БД в табличку пользователя добавь все эти колонки, исходя из класса адреса:

User table:

***varchar name, varchar last_name, ..., varchar country, varchar street, varchar city, integer house*** и т.д.

Больше инфо: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable